# Точность нейронной сети

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras

Нейронная сеть написанная с использованием `keras` определяет тональность отзывов (хороший/плохой). Использую датасет `imdb`; для векторизации использую `tfidf vectorizer` библиотеки `sklearn`. Проблема заключается в том, что при использовании обычного многослойного персептрона (несколько полносвязных слоев) точность сети достигает порядка 90%, но как только пытаюсь использовать любую другую топологию (сверточную или рекуррентную), то точность всегда в районе 50% и не повышается со временем обучения. Не могу понять в чем дело. Спасибо за помощь. Вот сама сеть (c такой топологией у меня точность около 90%):

```
positive_train_data = pd.read_csv('train_pos.tsv',sep = '\t')
negative_train_data = pd.read_csv('train_neg.tsv',sep = '\t')
positive_test_data = pd.read_csv('test_pos.tsv',sep = '\t')
negative_test_data = pd.read_csv('test_neg.tsv',sep = '\t')

positive_train_data = positive_train_data[['Text','Sentiment']]
negative_train_data = negative_train_data[['Text','Sentiment']]
positive_test_data = positive_test_data[['Text','Sentiment']]
negative_test_data = negative_test_data[['Text','Sentiment']]

train_data = pd.concat([positive_train_data,negative_train_data],ignore_index = True)
train_data = train_data.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

test_data = pd.concat([positive_test_data,negative_test_data],ignore_index = True)
test_data = test_data.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

data = pd.concat([positive_train_data,negative_train_data,positive_test_data,negative_test_data],ignore_index = True)
data.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
x = data.Text
y = data.Sentiment
SEED = 2000


x_train, x_test, y_train1, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 2000)
print( "Train set has total {0} entries with {1:.2f}% negative, {2:.2f}% positive".format(len(x_train),
                                                                             (len(x_train[y_train1 == 0]) / (len(x_train)*1.))*100,
                                                                            (len(x_train[y_train1 == 1]) / (len(x_train)*1.))*100))

print ("Test set has total {0} entries with {1:.2f}% negative, {2:.2f}% positive".format(len(x_test),
                                                                             (len(x_test[y_test == 0]) / (len(x_test)*1.))*100,
                                                                            (len(x_test[y_test == 1]) / (len(x_test)*1.))*100))

tvec1 = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=10000,ngram_range=(1, 2),use_idf=1,smooth_idf=1,sublinear_tf=1,stop_words = 'english')
tvec1.fit(x_train)

x_train_tfidf = tvec1.transform(x_train)
x_test_tfidf = tvec1.transform(x_test).toarray()



model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu', input_dim=1000))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(50,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

А с такой 50%:

```
model.add(Embedding(5000,64,input_length = 1000))
model.add(Conv1D(128,3,padding = 'same',))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(100,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько мне известно для классификации текстов лучше подходят рекуррентные нейронные сети - в частности LSTM (`Long short-term memory`).

Вот рабочий пример, где модель обучается на IMDB data set и имеет следующие характеристики:

- `num_words = 1000` (на моем железе, Tensorflow не поддерживает GPU, поэтому обучение больших моделей занимает неприлично много времени). Лучше конечно увеличить `num_words` хотя бы до 5000 слов.
- для обучения модели я использовал *20%* всех данных (опять же для ускорения)

Конфигурация NN:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 1000, 128)         128000
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 196)               254800
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 197
=================================================================
Total params: 382,997
Trainable params: 382,997
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Размерности наборов данных:

```
X_train.shape:  (8000, 1000)            Y_train.shape:  (8000,)
X_dev.shape:    (2000, 1000)            Y_dev.shape:    (2000,)
```

На моем древнем железе эта относительно небольшая модель обучалась около получаса.

Оценка точности:

```
In [9]: model.evaluate(X_dev, Y_dev)
2000/2000 [==============================] - 28s 14ms/step
Out[9]: [0.4211887891292572, 0.8225]

In [10]: Y_pred = model.predict(X_dev)

In [11]: Y_pred
Out[11]:
array([[0.81675935],
       [0.8283789 ],
       [0.7831746 ],
       ...,
       [0.10238472],
       [0.8915945 ],
       [0.36673504]], dtype=float32)

In [12]: np.squeeze(np.round(Y_pred))
Out[12]: array([1., 1., 1., ..., 0., 1., 0.], dtype=float32)

In [13]: (np.squeeze(np.round(Y_pred)) == Y_dev).mean()
Out[13]: 0.8225
```

Полный код программы:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer, text_to_word_sequence
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras import optimizers
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.models import load_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


def get_data(path, num_words, frac=1.0):
    p = Path(path)
    data = (pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', index_col=0)
                       for f in p.glob('*.tsv*')],
                      ignore_index=True)
              .sample(frac=frac))
    # build vocabulary
    tok = Tokenizer(num_words=num_words)
    tok.fit_on_texts(data['Text'])
    # convert texts to sequences
    X = tok.texts_to_sequences(data['Text'])
    return (pad_sequences(X, maxlen=num_words),
            data['Sentiment'], tok)

path = Path(r'D:\data\gDrive\My.Documents\Work\ML\SO\815234-Keras_text_classification')
num_words=1000

# read data
X, Y, tok = get_data(path, num_words=num_words, frac=0.2)

# split data set to train / dev
X_train, X_dev, Y_train, Y_dev = \
    train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=123, stratify=Y)
print('X_train.shape:\t{}\t\tY_train.shape:\t{}'.format(X_train.shape, Y_train.shape))
print('X_dev.shape:\t{}\t\tY_dev.shape:\t{}'.format(X_dev.shape, Y_dev.shape))


# build a model
embed_dim = 128
lstm_out = 196

# Model saving callback
model_filename = str(path / 'keras_model_LSTM')
ckpt_callback = ModelCheckpoint(model_filename, 
                                 monitor='val_loss', 
                                 verbose=1, 
                                 save_best_only=True, 
                                 mode='auto')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(num_words, embed_dim, input_length=num_words))
model.add(LSTM(lstm_out, recurrent_dropout=0.2, dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

# fit the model
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=32,
          validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[ckpt_callback])

model = load_model(model_filename)

print(model.evaluate(X_dev, Y_dev))

Y_pred = model.predict(X_dev)


###############################################################
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но прблема тут  в том, что я пробовал LSTM сеть(используя мой код, с tfidf) и все равно точность была 50%, даже на обучающей выборке. И я никак не могу понять в чем проблема

Comment: Вообще любая архитектура, кроме той, где используются только dense слои, дает точность не выше 50%

Comment: Не знаете в чем может быть дело? который день уже сижу бьюсь над данной проблемой и ничего

Comment: @Midnight, если посмотреть на примеры в сети по классификации текстов в Keras, то большинство использует метод, привиденный в моем ответе.

Comment: @Midnight, по видимому у вас неудачно подобраны параметры сети... 50% - это как раз точность сигмоида для генератора случайных чисел - 50% нулей и 50% единиц...

Comment: а какой метод векторизации использует ваш метод? Ну т.е как кодируются слова?

Comment: @Midnight, посмотрите на функцию `get_data()`...

Comment: Ошибка на выходе Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64'). на строке train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=123, stratify=Y)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76473/discussion-between-maxu-and-midnight).

Answer (score 0):

Свёрточные нейронные сети наиболее удачно используются для обработки изображений и прочих данных в виде матриц. Это следует из самой природы данных, которые вы обрабатываете: текст и изображения имеют разную структуру. Хотя искусственно им можно придать любую форму (перекодировать).

Вы же работаете с контекстом, поэтому лучше использовать LSTM.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).